# Is it possible to increase the data reception size with RS-232?

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

I am working with this RS-232 implementation: https://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/
on Windows operating system. I wrote a code in `C`, where one reads the input file and forwards it to the other participant. However, according to this implementation, I can load a maximum of 4096 bytes of data into the OS. Is it possible to increase this number? Because, for example, I sent a file with a size of 5MB and it took about 90 minutes at 9600 baud, but I do not want to increase baud

This is code for sender:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

// RS232 library
#include "rs232.h"

// Maximum size of data in block
#define INTERNALL_BUFFER 20480

// Size of static array
#define STATIC_ARRAY 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Checking, if was the correct program parameters have been entered
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nIt was the incorrect program parameters have been entered\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: test_tx file.suffix\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *stream;

    int cport_nr = 0,        /* /dev/ttyS0 (COM1 on windows) */
        bdrate = 9600,       /* 9600 baud */
        k = 1, fileSize = 0, /* k = counting, fileSize is size of data */
        true_count = 0, again = 0,
        sent_bytes = 0, begin = 0, last_block = 0,
        sent_size = INTERNALL_BUFFER; /* Maximum transfer size in block is sent_size */

    unsigned char convert[STATIC_ARRAY], *contents;

    // 8N1 means eight databits, no parity, one stopbit
    // If flowctrl is set to 0, no flow control is used
    char mode[] = {'8', 'N', '1', 0};

    size_t size;

    // Open file from CLI, find the size of it
    stream = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(stream);
    fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    // Allocate space for the entire file content
    contents = (unsigned char *)malloc(fileSize + 1);

    // Check if the memory has been successfully
    // allocated by malloc or not
    if (contents == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Stream file into memory
    size = fread(contents, 1, fileSize, stream);
    contents[size] = 0;
    fclose(stream);

    // Counting the number of blocks
    float count_blocks = fileSize / (float)INTERNALL_BUFFER;
    count_blocks = ceil(count_blocks);
    fprintf(stdout, "\nThe count of blocks sent will be: %.0f", count_blocks);

    // Opens the comport
    if (RS232_OpenComport(cport_nr, bdrate, mode, 0))
    {
        printf("Can not open comport\n");
        return (0);
    }

    //////Je mozne upravit prijem a odosielanie dat do funkcii/funkcie...

    // Convert int to char and send size
    sprintf((char *)convert, "%d", fileSize);
    printf("\nSize of data is: %d\n", fileSize);
    int annouc = RS232_SendBuf(cport_nr, convert, STATIC_ARRAY);
    if (annouc > 0)
        printf("\nThe size of the transmitted data was sent\n");

#ifdef _WIN32
    Sleep(5000);
#else
    usleep(1000000);     /* sleep for  1 Seconds */
#endif

    printf("\n");

    while (1)
    {
        int finish = 0;
        // If transmission will be repetead
        if (again)
        {
            begin = 0;
            again--;
        }

        // If the size of the data being sent is less than INTERNALL_BUFFER
        if (fileSize < sent_size)
            sent_size = fileSize;
        // Sends multiple bytes via the serial port
        sent_bytes = RS232_SendBuf(cport_nr, contents + begin, sent_size);
        if (sent_bytes < 0)
        {
            printf("Failed to send data\n");
            printf("Closed sending data and comport\n");
            break;
        }
        //  printf("%d.Sending: %d bytes.\n %.*s\n", k++, sent_bytes, sent_bytes,contents + begin);
        printf("%d.Sending: %d bytes\n", k++, sent_bytes);
        true_count++;
        begin += sent_bytes;

#ifdef _WIN32
        Sleep(3000);
#else
        usleep(1000000); /* sleep for  1 Seconds */
#endif
        int help_block = true_count;
        // If we want to send last less data than size of INTERNAL BUFFER
        if (++help_block == count_blocks)
            last_block++;
        if ((begin % sent_size == 0) && (last_block) && (begin != fileSize))
            sent_size = fileSize - begin;

        // Checking if sending data was successful or no
        while (begin == fileSize && true_count == (int)count_blocks)
        {
            int n = 0, result = 100;
            unsigned char buf[STATIC_ARRAY];
            n = RS232_PollComport(cport_nr, buf, STATIC_ARRAY);
            if (n > 0)
            {
                printf("\nReceiving: %d bytes\n%.*s\n", n, n, (char *)buf);
                result = memcmp(buf, "Sending of data was successful :)\n", n);
            }

            if (result == 0)
            {
                finish++;
                memset(buf, 0, n);
                break;
            }
            else if (result != 100)
            {
                memset(buf, 0, n);
                again++;
            }
        }

        if (finish)
            break;
    }

    printf("Finish...\n");
    printf("Closed RS232...\n");

    // Free memory aloccated
    free(contents);
    // Closes the serial port
    RS232_CloseComport(cport_nr);
    return 0;
}
```

The sender reads the input file, finds its size, sends the expected size to the other party and goes to send the file to the other party, knows how big the file is and follows accordingly. The problem is that the data transfer takes a very long time and the second thing that bothers me is that I want to send data, but the recipient must be able to process all the received data in blocks, I do not want data loss. If I increase the time for sleep, sending data passes without loss, but the sending time is, in my opinion, very long.

This is my application for RS-232 on Windows for read: github.com/jv813yh/example_rs232_blocks/blob/master/demo_rx.c –

I raised Baud to 115200, but this is my first application with RS232 and therefore I would need help or advice. For example, I want to transfer a file the size of a few MB, what Baud should I set? what transfer blocks to avoid buffer overnum? I'm sorry that I ask stupid questions, I also solve TCP / IP and I can't fully devote myself to RS-232. –

Comment: 90 minutes sounds about as good as it can get at 9600 baud. 5*10^6 B / 960 B/s (approximately) => 87 minutes. Do you use 8n1 (8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit)?

Comment: Yes, I use 8-N-1. But how do I deal with this situation when I send data of size n and the recipient can receive them multiple times to ensure that the recipient can catch all the data received at the sender sm increase the sleep time. Is it good practice or bad?

Comment: Compressing the data will typically reduce transmit time by 2.

Comment: Are you worried about transmission errors? If so, add a checksum of some sort. Either do it on individual blocks - or if errors are few, on the whole 5 MB file.

Comment: "where one reads the input file" --> If you post some of that file (~1000 bytes), various compression schemes could then be suggested, perhaps reducing transmit time significantly 2 to 100x.  As is, there is not enough info.

Comment: I do this by loading the input file, finding out its size, sending the expected size to the other side and going to send the file to the other party, it knows how big the file is and it follows accordingly. The problem is that the data transfer takes a very long time.

Comment: With RS-232 8-n-1, with select hardware, the stop bit may be shorten to about 0.6 of a stop bit, thus improving transmission time by about 4%.  Aside from that hardware tweak, you need to think of data tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in other answers and many comments, it does not help reduce communication time, which may be your real purpose, but you can change the receive (and send) buffer size.

It may be possible to achieve this by using this function of Win32API.
[SetupComm function (winbase.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setupcomm)

> `[in] dwInQueue`
> The recommended size of the device's internal input buffer, in bytes.
>
> `[in] dwOutQueue`
> The recommended size of the device's internal output buffer, in bytes.

There will be information in this function and the structure it informs about how big the buffer is actually.
[GetCommProperties function (winbase.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcommproperties)
[COMMPROP structure (winbase.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-commprop)

> `dwMaxRxQueue`
> The maximum size of the driver's internal input buffer, in bytes. A value of zero indicates that no maximum value is imposed by the serial provider.

However, as explained above, some device drivers may not have a buffer size setting function.

It may not be a good example, but the .NET SerialPort class allows you to set buffers from 4096 to 2G bytes (perhaps with a buffer inside the .NET class instance instead of the device driver?).
[SerialPort.ReadBufferSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

> The buffer size, in bytes. The default value is 4096; the maximum value is that of a positive int, or 2147483647.

---

**By the way**, although the title of the article says reception size, the description of the article and the source code presented only send it.
Which function or buffer size do you need to set after all?

---

**In response to comments:**

The RS232C library you are trying to use is not suitable for your purposes.
You probably chose one that supports cross-platform, is easy to use, and is easy to understand, but you can't use it to achieve anything more.

If you want really accurate and fast communication, you should look for a more sophisticated and flexible library or develop your own from scratch.
It cannot be achieved by a simple configuration change such as switching the baud rate.

It should have buffer size settings, hardware flow control, asynchronous completion notifications, etc. as basic functions.
On top of that, if you want fast file transfer without missing data or attributes, you will need to implement a protocol like ZMODEM.

Comment: This is my application for RS-232 on Windows for read: https://github.com/jv813yh/example_rs232_blocks/blob/master/demo_rx.c

Comment: I raised Baud to 115200, but this is my first application with RS232 and therefore I would need help or advice. For example, I want to transfer a file the size of a few MB, what Baud should I set? what transfer blocks to avoid buffer overnum? I'm sorry that I ask stupid questions, I also solve TCP / IP and I can't fully devote myself to RS-232.

Comment: @JozefVende Set the highest baud rate supported by both sides, but remember that unlike TCP, there's no automatic checking and resending if anything goes wrong.. You can probably hardcode a buffer size of 4096, but if you want to align it with the hardware, you have the answer in this answer. Use [`GetCommProperties`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcommproperties) and check the `dwMaxTxQueue` and `dwMaxRxQueue` members of the [`COMMPROP`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-commprop) struct (where `0` means no limit).

Answer (score 0):

RS-232 is a bit-oriented transport and as such 9600 baud defines the number of bits you can send a second.  Changing the buffering (4k in your example) will not impact the transmission speed; only how often the buffer needs to be replenished or flushed.